Error in header files in VS Code clang setup
This is the error i get. I have installed gcc, g++ and gdb using MSYS2, and clangd from LLVM.

Here are my compile_flags.txt (full) and settings.json (snippet).
Note : I use coderunner to compile and run the files.
-std=c++20
-Wall
-Wextra
-g

-IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0
-IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32
-IC:/msys64/mingw64/include

-IC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include

-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0
-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/14.2.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32
-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/include
-isystem C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/14.2.0/include

-nostdinc++
-D__GNUC__
-D__MSYS__
-D__STDC_HOSTED__

-I.

{
  "clangd.path": "C:\\LLVM\\bin\\clangd.exe",
  "clangd.arguments": [
    "--compile-commands-dir=.",
    "--query-driver=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe"
  ]
}

Any help to solve this error would be highly appreciated!

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.

Please only tag the programming language you're actually working with.

As for the problem, is it only an IntelliSense (and editor-specific) error, or do you get an error when you actually build as well?

The editor and the coderunner are using different json-files. Have you added the include paths to both?
